# Reference request: second fundamental form in Hermitian bundles

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

I am looking for a reference that details in precision what happens when dealing with subbundles of Hermitian holomorphic vector bundles. This topic is covered in Kobayashi's *Differential geometry of complex vector bundles* (Chapter I, section 6) but I find it extremely hard to understand in detail as the text skips many steps.

I have searched in the literature that I have available (Wells' *Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds*, Huybrechts' *Complex geometry*) but I cannot find a good exposition on the second fundamental form of a subbundle of a Hermitian vector bundle, and furthermore how to express the connection and curvatures of the subbundles in terms of the ambient one.

For a brief exposition of what I am looking for: suppose $E\rightarrow M$ is a Hermitian holomorphic subbundle with the Hermitian connection $D$ (metric compatible and $D^{(0,1)}=0$). I want to express the curvature of the Hermitian bundle $E$ in terms on the curvatures of the subbundles $S,S^\perp \subset E$, where $S$ is a *holomorphic* subbundle.

My aim is to understand the following formula in detail:

$$
R = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
R_S - B\wedge B^* & D^{(1,0)}B\\
-D^{(0,1)}B^* & R_{S^\perp} - B^*\wedge B
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $B$ is the second fundamental form of $S$ within $E$.

Comment: The [original paper](https://publications.ias.edu/node/185) by Griffiths on this is very readable. Demailly's [book](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf) (Chapter 5.14, page 273) also has a nice account.